# T-SQL remove cross pairs from table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem with removing cross pairs from table.

Example table:

```
  X1     X2 
-------------
  1       2 
  2       1
  1       2 
  3       2
  2       3
  1       3
```

Expected result

```
  X1     X2 
------------
  1       2 
  1       3
```

Currently I am thinking about looping through table rows and removing reference row and duplicate row if found, but maybe I can do it in one query? Any help would be welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Are there pairs without any cross pair duplicates?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hmmm . . . If I understand correctly, you want to enumerate the pairs and then cancel out against the reversed pair.  Here is one method:

```
with t as (
      select x1, x2, row_number() over (partition by x1, x2 order by x1) as seqnum
      from mytable t
     ) 
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t.x2 = t2.x1 and t.x1 = t2.x2 and t.seqnum = t2.seqnum
                 );
```

**Results**

```
x1  x2  seqnum
1   2   2
1   3   1
```